# Can't get int from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I simply want to get one field from my NSDictionary. I want to get integer variable, but something is very strange.

I want to show you a screenshot from Xcode, there I get variables values. Variable 'price' is integer and should be equal to 0, can you help me?

[image]

I create this Dictionary in such way:

```
NSDictionary * dict    = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"price"]], @"price",
                                      pairedData2, @"uniqueName",
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"],@"wasPurchased",
                                      [dictionary objectForKey:@"link"],@"videoLink",
                                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"enable"]], @"enable",
                                      nil];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `price` key is either an `NSString` with the value of `@"0"` or it is an `NSNumber` with the value of `0`. You don't provide enough info to know which of the two it is.

In your debugger, you first do (I'm abbreviating):

> po dict[@"price"]

and this gives the expected and correct output of:

> 0

since that is the value of the `NSNumber` or `NSString`.

Then you do:

> po dict[@"price"] == 0

and you get:

> false

Which is again the correct and expected result. You get `false` because the result of `dict[@"price"]` is a non-nil object pointer and you are asking if the pointer is `nil` (`== 0` is the same as `== nil`). Since you can't store `nil` objects in the dictionary, the result isn't `nil` and `false` is reported.

To see if the value of the `NSNumber` or `NSString` is `0`, you should do:

> po dict[@"price"].intValue == 0

and you would receive the desire result of:

> true

Your last attempt of:

> po dict[@"price"].intValue

resulted in:

> nil

This is again the correct result because the value of `dict[@"price"].intValue` is the `int` value of `0`. But you used `po` which means `print object` so the `0` is interpreted as `nil`. If you do:

> p dict[@"price"].intValue

you will get the desired result of:

> 0

Use `po` to print object values. Use `p` to print primitive values (such as `int`).

Answer (score 0):

Variable price can't be  integer.
Every key and value in NSDictionary has to be an NSObject.
Therefore it is probably an NSNumber. Retrieving an NSNumber value is done like that:

```
NSNumber *number = @(2);
int numberAsInt = number.intValue;
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I edited my question and showed how I create this dictionary. I save this zero as NSSting(

Comment: You can still use intValue. 
NSString *numberAsString = @"2"; int number = numberAsString.intVAlue